# creating virtual bridge breaks host network

Tags: kvm-virtualization, linux-networking, switch, xen, bridge

Tried to set up virtual bridge on a Ubuntu machine, and host network broke

```
#ip link add name br0 type bridge
#ip link set dev eth0 master br0
#ip link set dev br0 up

#ping <gateway_addr> // failed
#ip neigh 
<gateway_addr> dev eth0 FAILED

#echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/conf/ipv4/br0/arp_accept
#ping <gateway_addr> // failed
#ip neigh
<gateway_addr> dev eth0 FAILED
<gateway_addr> dev br0 lladdr <mac_addr> REACHABLE
```

Ping to gateway doesn't succeed, however it does when I delete the bridge and remove it as a master of eth0. What am I missing. Please advise!

Comment: when you attach a bridge to an interface, do you also make sure the interface has no IP configured and the bridge has the server's IP instead?

Comment: No. And, I understand what you mean, if I do so, it would work. But, bridge is not supposed to have an IP address? Does it? here is where my concept is questioning me. Please advise!

Comment: When you set up a bridge, it is the bridge device that should have an IP address, not the individual interfaces that are part of the bridge.

Comment: That is what I am saying, it a bridge/switch and not a router, theoretically it doesn't have to have an IP assigned to it? Am I missing something.

Comment: Okay, even if I assume virtual bridge is assigned an IP, why do I have to flush the IP of host ethernet interface, isn't it connected to the bridge? Either my concept is wrong or something else is wrong.

Comment: As per my understanding bridge's job is to store and forward packets destined to adjoining LAN, if not reject if destined to source LAN.  Am I missing something? Please advise!

Comment: You understand correctly what the bridge does. But it also becomes the de-facto interface for the host, because the NIC becomes a slave which doesn't do the actual communication any longer, attached to a bridge it is simply another port. If it helps you understand - in a switch you don't assign IPs to ports, but you definitely assign an IP to the switch, if you want to configure and monitor it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, taking it down here as an answer.

Your bridge is the interface that should have the IP configuration, the NIC (or bond, if you have one) becomes a dummy used by the bridge as a physical port to forward the packets out through, and should not hold an IP.

Comment: So, as the bridge has to send the packets from guest machines out, and if the eth0 is on same LAN it would be not the bridge way to send out via eth0. So, it will keep eth0 as dummy to forward the packets out. Correct me! I still have a follow up question. Are you aware of VMnet0? it is configured by VMware networking. It is a bridge that lets the guest machines NICs connect to host LAN, still it doesn't touch host IP address. Do you know how does that work? https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-4D35D1FC-5926-45A8-96B1-42C922DA97E9.html

Comment: VMnet0 is the virtual adapter / bridge created by the VMWare hypervisor. If it is configured as a host-only network, then only guest VMs can talk to each other via that, and it is completely separate from other host network adapters.

Comment: And, if it configured to use host LAN?